# Moving onpage CSS elements into one CSS file

Tags: css

I have taken on a website that has all it's CSS on the individual pages. Although it only has around 10 HTML pages, I'm wondering if there's a quick way to extract all those CSS elements into one CSS file and add a link to the stylesheet on each individual page without having to do it manually.

It might seem a tad lazy but it's likely I'm going to be working on sites done by the same designer a few more times after this one and the HTML based CSS is actually slowing the site down considerably, especially for a simple HTML, no frills site.

Any help on automating this would be most useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe bear.css helps: http://bearcss.com/

Comment: I'm not sure if "the HTML based CSS is actually slowing the site down considerably" will be solved by putting the CSS in a separate stylesheet. The total amount of data per HTML page won't decrease, but you will have more files to load. So do some testing to make sure!

Comment: You could use JavaScript to pull all the style attributes out and output them, but any solution I can think of that would do this completely, correctly and quickly would take longer to create than manually pulling out the CSS, which also gives you an opportunity to clean everything up.

Comment: Be careful of conflicting styles, he might have named them the same but with different values.

Comment: @MrLister the CSSfile will only be downloaded once and cached when the user visits the other pages. So the first load will take slightly longer due to 1 extra file request, but following loads will take less time because the CSS file is cached.

Comment: Interesting question. Best I can come up with is Notepad++, some regular expression magic, and a bit of autoformatting to finish off the stylesheet. Beware though, if you think [regular expressions can solve your problem...](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should try the http://unused-css.com/ site, quote:

> Explore the pages of your site **automatically**, find the unused CSS selectors and **create new clean CSS** files you can download.